# Syntax for generic types parameterized by generic records

Tags: generics, types, f#

Suppose I have defined the generic record

```
type GenericType1<'T> = {MyField : 'T}
```

and I want to define another generic type parametrized by this type. Following my C# nose, I would write something like this:

```
type GenericType2<'T, GenericType1<'T> > = class end
```

Unfortunately, this does not work, nor does this:

```
type GenericType2<'T, 'S when 'S :> GenericType1<'T> > = class end
```

because GenericType1, being a record, is sealed and the compiler won't accept the subtype constraint. If GenericType1 is a **class**, however, the above **does work**.

So, my question is: **what syntax should I use to define GenericType2 which is parameterized by the record GenericType1**?

Comment: Your first example doesn't work in C# either: `public class GenericType2<T, GenericType<T>> { }` results in the error "Type parameter declaration must be an identifier not a type".  Could you clarify the actual scenario you're hoping to achieve?

Comment: Why not just write `GenericType1<'T>` in `GenericType2`'s body wherever you would otherwise write `'S`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, records are sealed, so what exactly would such a subtype constraint mean? You can do the following without an additional type arg.

```
type GenericType2<'T>() = 
    member val MyRecord = {MyField=Unchecked.defaultof<'T>}
```

Does that cover your use case?

Comment: I understand why I'm getting the error. Unfortunately though, your example doesn't address my problem. I need to parameterize GenericType2 by GenericType1 as indicated where GenericType1 is a record. This is certainly doable in C# with classes (as it is in F#). But if it can't be one in F# with records, I will need to change my approach...

Comment: Records are sealed. What are you trying to do?